# Joining string and list

Tags: python, python-3.x

`list_1` contains a list of URLs. After joining string and the list, the output seems like this:

> "http://www.imdb.com['/title/tt2338151/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=3376940102&pf_rd_r=0Z7H698B14B7XQ2ERWGA&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_250']"

I dont want [' and ] in it. Below is the code I am using.

```
for links in list_1:
   new=links
   new_link='http://www.imdb.com'+str(links)
   list_2.append(new_link)

print(list_2)
```

Comment: instead of new=links use links=links[2:len(links)-2]

Comment: use `"".join(links)` instead of `str(links)`

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = ["someurl", "someurl2"]
list_2 = []

new_link = "http://www.imdb.com/"
for links in list_1:

   new_link = new_link + "".join(links)

print(new_link)

'http://www.imdb.com/someurlsomeurl2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str` on a list will include the `[` and `]` indicating a list. If you want to leave these off, one way you could do it is just to leave these characters off of the string by only selecting the second to second-last characters, using `[1:-1]`. For example, using this in your code:

```
for links in list_1:
   new=links
   new_link='http://www.imdb.com'+str(links)[1:-1]
   list_2.append(new_link)
```

This will preserve the commas and spaces between the items (not sure based on the question if this is wanted or not, only the brackets were mentioned). If all of the items in the list are strings already, you can use `join` instead, which will remove the commas and spaces:

```
for links in list_1:
   new=links
   new_link='http://www.imdb.com'+''.join(links)
   list_2.append(new_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for links in list_1:
   new=links
   links=links[2:len(links)-2] #removed [' from front and '] from back
   new_link='http://www.imdb.com'+str(links)
   list_2.append(new_link)

print(list_2)
```